# regex alternation with similar words in a phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning JavaScript and trying to develop a regex pattern for similar phrases. Here is what I have currently:

```
var regEx = /(?:[^"']|^)(show me a picture|show me a photo|show me a photograph)(?!["'])/i;
```

I have been trying to understand alternation but the result of this regex is that it will only match `show me a picture` & `show me a photo` but not `show me a photograph`. My understanding is that regex already has found `show me a photo` so it stops there.

I am unable to find the regex that will also account for the `show me a photograph` phrase.

Perhaps this isn't the most efficient way to do this which is why I am having the issue.

Comment: Just put `show me a photograph` before `show me a photo`: `var regEx = /(?:[^"']|^)(show me a picture|show me a photograph|show me a photo)(?!["'])/i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regEx to capture whole phrase (word) like this:

```
var regEx = /(?:[^"']|^)(\bshow me a picture\b|\bshow me a photo\b|\bshow me a photograph\b)(?!["'])/ig;
```

Comment: Is this method more effective than changing the order of the phrases as the other answers suggest? Both methods seem to have the same effect, just a different way of going about it.

Comment: it gives you exact phrase matches. In fact, for this example it is enough single pattern like this: `var regEx = /(?:[^"']|^)(\bshow me a p(i|h)\w+\b)(?!["'])/ig;`

Comment: Interesting! I like this method as well because it gives a little more flexibility in terms of it not returning an exact phrase match. I did not realize that this was possible. Very helpful to have examples of different patterns.

Comment: A small off-topic. Regular Expressions, `"patterns"` were invented to help modeling brain processes. They were things _per se_ for long time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript regex spec says this:

> The `|` regular expression operator separates two alternatives. The pattern first tries to match the left Alternative (followed by the sequel of the regular expression); if it fails, it tries to match the right Disjunction (followed by the sequel of the regular expression).

Therefore, if you ask for a match for `show me a photo|show me a photograph`, the left-hand alternative will always be preferred. Put them in the other order if you want the `photograph` one to take priority.